# can i add textfields in the code other than in the init?

Tags: java, swing

Im a 15 year old noob to java. I am trying to make a basic program trader that asks for the stock price, the stock name, the stock market value and the type of order. Based on the type of order, i want a new textfield to appear. do i have to add the textfield in the init first or can i do it in the action performed.  I googled someother ones but they are a little too complicated for me. heres my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
// import an extra class for the ActionListener
import java.awt.event.*;


public class mathFair extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    TextField stockPrice2;
    TextField stockName2;
    TextField orderType2;
    TextField marketValue2;
    TextField buyOrder2;
    TextField sellOrder2;
    TextField limitOrder2;
    TextField stopLossOrder2;
    Label stockPrice1;
    Label stockName1;
    Label orderType1;
    Label marketValue1;
    Label buyOrder1;
    Label sellOrder1;
    Label limitOrder1;
    Label stopLossOrder1;
    Button calculate;





public void init()
{

          stockPrice1 = new Label ("Enter Stock Price:");

          stockName1 = new Label ("Enter Name of Stock: ");

          orderType1 = new Label ("Enter Type of Order: 1 for Buy, 2 for Sell, 3 for Stop Loss, 4 for Limit");

          marketValue1= new Label("Enter The Current Price Of The Market");





          stopLossOrder1 = new Label ("Enter The Lowest Price The Stock Can Go");

          limitOrder1 = new Label ("Enter The Highest Price The Stock Can Go");

          stockPrice2 = new TextField (35);

          stockName2 = new TextField (35);

          orderType2 = new TextField (35);

          marketValue2= new TextField(35);

          calculate= new Button("Start The Simulation");

          add (stockPrice1);

          add (stockPrice2);

          add (stockName1);

          add (stockName2);

          add (marketValue1);
                  ;
          add(marketValue2);

          add (orderType1);

          add (orderType2);

          add(calculate);


         ;



          calculate.addActionListener(this);






 }






             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
             {

                    String stock= stockPrice2.getText();
                    int stockPrice= Integer.parseInt(stock);
                    stockPrice2.setText(stockPrice +"");


                    String marketV= marketValue2.getText();
                    int marketValue= Integer.parseInt(marketV);
                    marketValue2.setText(marketValue+"");




                    String orderT= orderType2.getText();
                    int orderType= Integer.parseInt(orderT);
                    orderType2.setText(orderType+"");



                    if((e.getSource()==calculate)&& (orderType==1))
                    {
                        buyOrder2= new TextField(35);
                        buyOrder1 = new Label("Enter Price You Would Like To Buy At");
                        add(buyOrder2);
                        add(buyOrder1);
                    }
                    else
                    if((e.getSource()==calculate)&& (orderType==2))
                    {
                         sellOrder2= new TextField(35);
                         sellOrder1 = new Label("Enter Price You Would Like To Sell At");
                         add(sellOrder2);
                         add(sellOrder1);

                    }
                    else
                    if((e.getSource()==calculate)&& (orderType==3))
                    {

                        stopLossOrder2= new TextField(35);
                        stopLossOrder1=new Label("Enter The Lowest Price The Stock Can Go");
                        add(stopLossOrder2);
                        add(stopLossOrder1);


                    }
                    else
                    if((e.getSource()==calculate)&& (orderType==4))
                    {

                        limitOrder2=new TextField(35);
                        limitOrder1= new Label("Enter the Highest Price The Stock Can Go");
                        add(limitOrder2);
                        add(limitOrder1);;
                    }


            }

}
```

Comment: ... So you're asking if something is possible, and then you apparently have tried it, and... well, **did it work**? If not, what/how exactly didn't go as planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add any new UI component from within the `actionPerformed` method. However, you would probably need to let the layouting engine know that something has changed, so it can rearrange the layout.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to instantiate the Textfield object,i.e, declare in init() method, after which actionPerformed method event will be invoked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What UI style are you using? On a form on an interactive logon (traditional desktop application style) then the forms usually are all about adding new elements on the fly (altho you generally have to specify *where* to put the new elements). Web frameworks (where I live most of the day) however, do *not* usually just let you put new elements, or at least, not if you're going to use them after a post back.

The reason is due to the lifecycle of the underlying host object for the textfield. In a web app, every page is it's own instantiation. There is no server-side state to speak of (ok, I lie, we do have server-side state, but it's not a concept inherent in the HTTP design). So (using my beloved ASP.NET as an example) I can't add a textfield *after* a postback and expect it to be populated with data from the POST values, because I didn't create it before the POST data populated (so I *could* create it in the form init area). However, I can dynamically create whatever element I wanted after the response was started knowing that it'll only be good for that particular generation of data.

Ok, now that I've thoroughly confused you, try this:

Desktop app - create textboxes to your hearts content (but place them)
Web app - understand statelessness before creating dynamic controls for the user to work with

---

And welcome to programming `;)`